# Access SQL Query, Find when the most recent expiration date for employees will be

Tags: sql

I keep track of employees training for a CPI course. I only want to see when their certificate is going to expire.

This is what I see currently:

```
Employee Name     Expiration Date
Jane Doe          June 5, 2014
Jane Doe          May 10, 2013
Jim Smith         July 6, 2014
Jim Smith         June 10, 2013
Bob Turner        November 10 ,2015       
Bob Turner        November 10, 2014
```

This is what I want to see:

```
Employee Name     Expiration Date
Jane Doe          June 5, 2014
Jim Smith         July 6, 2014
Bob Turner        November 10 ,2015
```

Comment: It's going to be tough to answer this question without more background. What are your tables? What's the query that gives you the data you're describing?

Comment: Sorry about. I have a table with the following columns employee name, certification, recertification, date completed, and expiration date. I the query I ran was with all those fields but I did not know how to show only when their most recent certificate will expire. I do not need to query if they had taken a certification class or recertification class just when their cetificate expires. Does that Help?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, based on your edit

```
    SELECT [Employee name], MAX([expiration Date])
    from [Your Table]
    GROUP BY [Employee name]
```

Comment: Great, glad it helped. If you've got a moment, could you possibly upvote my answer and "accept" it with the tick, to indicate it was helpful and solved your problem?